# Set up a serial port with VirtualBox on Ubuntu (guest OS : Windows XP)

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port

I'm having trouble for a few weeks now trying to access the serial port of my computer when working on the guest OS Windows XP Pro via VirtualBox. The host OS is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and I'm using VirtualBox 5.0.18. In its settings, I've set up the serial port as on this screenshot:

[image]

...but then I can't run the virtual machine:

[image]

I've already asked the VirtualBox forum but they replied it was more a Ubuntu problem than a VB one, so I'm asking for help here!

The thing I'm trying to do is to back up an old device (from the early 2000s or late 1990s), which back-up software can only be opened on Windows. I've managed to install and open it on my XP guest OS, but it cannot communicate with the peripheral device.

Excuse me if I'm not always intelligible, I'm not used to run Ubuntu and I'm French, so my English may not be perfect!

Thanks in advance though :)

Lucas

Answer (score 6):

Your user is not in the group that has access the serial port. You can either run Virtualbox as root *(Not recommended )*, or add your user to the group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>
```

You might have to logout and login again to make this work.

*Cheers*

Comment: Thanks! Done. Now the virtual machine works but the peripheral device is still not recognised...

Comment: I take it you've installed the Virtualbox guest additions?

Comment: Yes I did just after intalling VirtualBox...

Comment: Okay. So just for clarification: Windows XP has the Guest Additions, you have enabled the serial port but XP still doesn't see a virtual type 16450 serial port? Or has it detected it, but isn't connecting with the old device?

Comment: Now, Windows is unable to run (blue screen and automatic reboot, I can't do anything). I don't know why...

Comment: No, Windows XP doesn't have the Guest Additions, I thought you were talking about VirtualBox, sorry...

Comment: Ohhh. The guest additions are for the virtual machines, not for the host. They can be installed into the VM by starting the machine(Disable the serial port first, if that helps it booting normally again), in the Virtualbox window, go to **Devices** > **Insert Guest Additions CD image** and it'll put a cd in the virtual drive. Install the additions and try enabling the serial port again.

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened but even when I disable the serial ports and the I/O APIC, I can't run XP anymore...

Comment: **WHELP** Something got messed up. This is pretty much the limit of my knowledge. Sorry

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm for me: Ubuntu 18.04.1 host + VBox 5.2.10 + Win7 guest Seial/USB adapter used to access Cisco-like serial console on EdgeCore switch.

Answer (score 4):

First check the actual permissions on your host system. Something like:

`~ ls -l /dev/ttyS0`

Mine is:

`crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 2016-05-24 07:34:52 /dev/ttyS0`

This means thay either I need to be root (first 'rw-' from left) or I need to be in the dialout group (second 'rw-' from left).
Try from command line a check with command `id` like:

`~ id
uid=1000(enzo) gid=1000(enzo) groups=1000(enzo),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),127(sambashare)`

In this case I cannot access that serial port. So I can add myself to `dialout` group:

`~ sudo usermod -a -G dialout enzo`

where `enzo` is your very userid as shown above by command `id`
Then you need to logout and log back in in orderto have this change effective.

Comment: `ls -l /dev/ttyS0` returns `crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 mai   24 16:59 /dev/ttyS0`

`id` returns `uid=1000(manivelles) gid=1000(manivelles) groupes=1000(manivelles),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),125(vboxusers)`

Answer (score 1):

I use a USB adapter im my Dell Inspiron.

```
$ lsusb | grep Serial

Bus 001 Device 012: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

```
$ dmesg | grep pl2303

[13131.366817] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303

[13131.366830] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303

[13131.366847] pl2303 1-2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected

[13131.367526] usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

So I changed `/dev/ttyS0` to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and it works like a charm.